# Scroll the page in iPhone view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have a view which has details of some event,which includes imageview, some labels etc.
I have the description of the event as a small subview in the view which is scrollable as below.

```
CGRect descriptionTextViewRect = CGRectMake(15, 185, 280, 85);
descriptionText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:descriptionTextViewRect];
descriptionText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
descriptionText.text =des;
descriptionText.editable = NO;
descriptionText.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
descriptionText.clipsToBounds = YES;
descriptionText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
descriptionText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
[scrollView addSubview: descriptionText];
```

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046449/calculate-the-contentsize-of-scrollview) but I get scrollable for both text view as well as the scrollview

I followed like this

```
float sizeOfContent = 0;
 int i ;

for (i=0; i<[scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
    sizeOfContent += descriptionText.frame.size.height;
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(descriptionText.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent)
```

I need to display the whole content of the description and make the whole detail page scrollable.

Am I doing it correctly? Or am I missing out somthing?

How do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same item's height for several times.

This:

```
for (i=0; i<[scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
    sizeOfContent += descriptionText.frame.size.height;
}
```

Should be this:

```
for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
    sizeOfContent += view.frame.size.height;
}
```

So it will correctly add all item's heights to `sizeOfContent`.

Comment: exactly , but i need to set the size of the description text and make the detail page scrollable. I am now able to scroll only the description text. Can you advice on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding subView at same position every time. For example: if you are adding 5 subViews it should be like as followings:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
CGRect descriptionTextViewRect = CGRectMake(15, i*185, 280, 85);
descriptionText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:descriptionTextViewRect];
descriptionText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
descriptionText.text =des;
descriptionText.editable = NO;
descriptionText.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
descriptionText.clipsToBounds = YES;
descriptionText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
descriptionText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
[scrollView addSubview: descriptionText];
}
```