# Can't add a UIScrollView to a part of the view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, contentsize

Inside a `UIViewController`, I need to have the bottom half scrollable. So I added a `UIScrollView` and positioned it halfway down the view's height. And in the `viewDidAppear` method, I have put the below two code lines to make it scrollable.

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

This way works if the scroll view fills the entire view, I've tested. But this method didn't work for my need. The scroll view would automatically move up and take up the entire screen. I assumed it was the second line of code which causes this.

So I removed the scroll view, added two `UIView`s to the view controller. To the bottom view, I added the `UIScrollView`. And in the `viewDidAppear` method, I have put the same two code lines changing the second line to refer the frame of the `UIView` that contains the scroll view..

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.frame = self.containerView.frame;
```

But it wouldn't scroll either.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: viewDidAppear seems to be a wrong place for setting frame. Use viewDidLoad instead. Plus `CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);` if the sizes proved are not greater than the scrollView dimension, it won't scroll. Check those.

Comment: @JeslyVarghese Small progress. Before I moved the code to `viewDidLoad`, it looked like [this](http://i.imgur.com/kyrjm6M.png). But after, it became [this](http://i.imgur.com/uM6c2yk.png). But sadly still it doesn't scroll. I checked the `self.scrollView.frame.size.height` and it's greater than the view's height.

Comment: @Isuru Dude, lol don't set absolute values for your content size man. you dont want magic numbers all over your code, it makes your application unreadable for the next programmer. It's best to have it based on the size of the content that's actually inside your scrollview so that your scrollview always scrolls to cover all your content inside it.

Comment: @Isuru: I might be very wrong. but turn off auto layout for the time.

Comment: @Isuru Also, remember your **scrollview will only scroll if the contentsize is greater than the scrollview's frame**. As i made clear in my answer, you dont want absolute values for your contentSize, calculate the contentSize based on the content inside your scrollview by keep tabs of the height as you add content to your scrollview for example.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you keep setting the frame of the scrollView to something completely different from what you're actually trying to achieve.

If all you want to do is setup your scroll view so that it only occupies half the space then  why dont you just set the `frame` so that the `height` only covers the portion of the screen that you want it to cover; and then set the `x & y` coordinates so that you draw the scroll view from the right position.

Do something like this:

```
//Shortcut to view's frame.
CGRect viewsFrame = self.view.frame;

/**
CGRectMake takes 4 parameters: x, y, width, height
x: is set to 0 since you want the scrollview to start from the left with no margin
y: you want the y position to start half way, so we grab the view's height and divide by 2  
width: you want your scrollview to span from left to right, so simply grab the view's width
height: you want your scrollview's height to be half of your screen height, so get view's height and divide by 2.
*/
CGRect frameForSV = CGRectMake(0, viewsFrame.size.height/2, viewsFrame.size.width, viewsFrame.size.height/2);

UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frameForSV];
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
```

Then set your content size not based on an ansolute value, its best to have it based on the size of the content that's actually inside your scrollview so that your scrollview always scrolls to cover all your content inside it.

Also, remember that your **scrollview will only scroll if the contentsize is greater than the scrollview's frame**

**UPDATE 1** after reading your comment in this post simply comment out any code in your `viewController.m` file related to your `scrollview` since youre setting up everything in interface builder.

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. Scroll views is my bane in iOS developing. I managed to get it almost working. I don't want to create the scroll view programatically so I did it in IB. Now it scrolls perfectly except for [this](http://i.imgur.com/VpxHVeX.png) issue. As you can see the gap between the above `UIView` and the `UIScrollView`. When it runs, there's a huge gap between them. I have added all the necessary constraints but no luck. Any idea what's causing this issue?

Comment: Can you post your xcode project or something so I can have a quick look?

Comment: About the content size, the content inside the scroll view won't change. It'll have a fixed height. Do I still have to change it to get the size based on the content? Also can you please show an example on that?

Comment: If it's fixed then cool, no problem :) Normally one would do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046449/calculate-the-contentsize-of-scrollview So they can get a dynamic contentSize should the content every be updated in a scrollView

Comment: [Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xeggp9ocpfi6fai/ScrollViewTest.zip) a test project with the issue.

Comment: @Isuru remove all programmatic code linked to your scrollview since everything is done on interface builder.

Comment: Removing all your code related to your scrollview in your 'viewController.m' file fixes the problem. You will only be left with a very small mergin at the top of your scrollview, thats because of the way you've positioned it in interface builder otherwise that huge gap is gone now.

Comment: It fixes the layout problem but it won't scroll now.

Comment: @isuru, oh aha so you have more content inside it. Ok cool one moment. Then you simply need to set the contentSize. One moment

Comment: @Isuru Just a quick one, can I ask how you plan to populate your scrollview because at the moment it seems as though you've put random views in there just to try and get scrolling to work. If you can tell me what you will actually end up putting in there then that would be great

Comment: I'm actually gonna put a single `UIView` with a fixed height (520 to be exact) in it.

Comment: @great, thats what I needed to hear. Cool

Comment: Yep, I got everything working. I deleted all constraints, I deleted all the junk you had in the scrollview, I also deleted the scrollview, and the extra green view was deleted too. I was left with the bare bones of the viewcontroller, Ie, a view and thats it. Then I added a new scrollview, and progammatically added a UIView with a height of 520. And it was all scrolling nicely.

Comment: All in all, it felt that something was wrong with one of your constraints which was causing it to conflict with the scrolling.